# Execution Failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gradle

When I create a new flutter project the project always failed to run and output the exception that shown in the below

I tried to delete the folder .gradle and rerun the project but I get the same problem how can I solve this problem?
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':gradle:compileGroovy'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':gradle:detachedConfiguration1'.
> Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:?.?.??.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/?.?.??/groovy-?.?.??.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/?.?.??/groovy-?.?.??.pom
> Required by:
> project :gradle
> Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-ant:?.?.??.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-ant/?.?.??/groovy-ant-?.?.??.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-ant/?.?.??/groovy-ant-?.?.??.pom
> Required by:
> project :gradle
> Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-astbuilder:?.?.??.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-astbuilder/?.?.??/groovy-astbuilder-?.?.??.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-astbuilder/?.?.??/groovy-astbuilder-?.?.??.pom
> Required by:
> project :gradle

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  BUILD FAILED in 4s
  Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
  The Flutter CLI developer tool uses Google Analytics to report usage and diagnostic data
  along with package dependencies, and crash reporting to send basic crash reports.
  This data is used to help improve the Dart platform, Flutter framework, and related tools.
  Telemetry is not sent on the very first run.
  To disable reporting of telemetry, run this terminal command:
  flutter --disable-telemetry.
  If you opt out of telemetry, an opt-out event will be sent,
  and then no further information will be sent.
  This data is collected in accordance with the
  Google Privacy Policy .
  Please note that analytics reporting was already disabled, and will continue to be disabled.

[This is the exception in debug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCn8P.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem because of the new version of flutter 3.13 I face this problem and there is the solution:
 1. Download the previous version for flutter like 3.10    
   
 2. delete your .gradle from your system disk the path of the folder like: C:\Users'your user name'

3.Rerun the project again

-  if this doesn't work do this with the previous steps :

1. make your system in ENGLISH if the system in another language   
     
2. make sure the path of flutter that you added to enviroment variable is in Lowercase and dont have any symbol there is an example how it should to be: C:\development\flutter\bin  'Notice: if the path have any Uppercase or custom symbol you have to edit the name of the folders in your windows explorer then add the path to enviroment variable '

3.Make sure your Regional Format in US from:
Settings -> Time & Language -> Region -> Regional Format

4. delete your .gradle from your system disk the path of the folder like: C:\Users'your user name

5.Rerun the project again

Comment: thanks for answering, The solution of downgrade the flutter version working correctly

Comment: I'm using flutter 3.16.  I had other problems too.  I just deleted the .gradle folder and things started working again.  (The rebuild took a while.)